# length > 1 but only done once in for loop

Tags: vb.net

Code :

```
Private Sub RefreshToDoList() Handles MyBase.Load
    If FileExists(NewEvent.ToDoItems_Path) And FileExists(NewEvent.ToDoDates_Path) And FileExists(NewEvent.ToDoContents_Path) Then
        If Not ContentOf(NewEvent.ToDoItems_Path).ToString = "" And Not ContentOf(NewEvent.ToDoDates_Path).ToString = "" And Not ContentOf(NewEvent.ToDoContents_Path).ToString = "" Then
            ToDoListItems = ContentOf(NewEvent.ToDoItems_Path).ToString.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            ToDoListDates = ContentOf(NewEvent.ToDoDates_Path).ToString.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            ToDoListContents = ContentOf(NewEvent.ToDoContents_Path).ToString.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        End If


        If ToDoListItems.Length = ToDoListDates.Length And ToDoListItems.Length = ToDoListContents.Length Then
            For count As Integer = 0 To ToDoListItems.Length - 1
                ToDoListBox.Items.Add(ToDoListItems(count))
                ToDoListInfo(count) = "Date : " + ToDoListDates(count) + Convert.ToString(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine) + "Content : " + ToDoListContents(count)
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Checked, and `ToDoListItems.Length` is `3` but there is only one item in `ToDoListBox`.

What's the problem in this code? It seemed to be in the for loop.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the for loop and step through it. That should reveal what is going on.

Comment: What does it mean? @SSS

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx @user3698272

Comment: Everything was only ran once in the `for` loop.

Comment: It appears that your code is handling `MyBase.Load`.  Is that the Load event for a Form?  If so, check the output window for any exceptions.